# Navbar toggler is not working in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, togglebutton, bootstrap-5

I've been experiencing some issues with navbar using Bootstrap 5.0.2 dist. Navbar toggler appears and collapse but do not roll back after clicking bar icon. I am using navbar-fixed from bootstrap 5 examples page. I've added all links in head and scripts below. I've also added custom css file for this navbar - still don't work properly. Please suggest me what is not right. Here is the code:

```
    <!-- Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: pro tip : you can add the common tags like the [html] tag to attract more views instead of using multiple similar tags

Comment: @I_love_vegetables but the issue is more related to Bootstrap 5 and it's css and js not html itself

Comment: Ok i've added html tag maybe this will help. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved. I've added bootstrap.min.js together with bootstrap.bundle.js - so the script executed two times and generated issues. I left only bootstrap.bundle.js and everything is working fine.